# How can I resolve "Low disk space" errors of Ubuntu system on VM

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I have a problem that "low disk space on filesystem root" of Ubuntu system on VMware.
I tried to solve it from many tutorials but it didn't work well.
Could anyone help me plz?
I look forward to your kind response.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MswJj.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1oE9.png)

Comment: Just as an aside: the screenshots suggest a confusion on part of the tutorial you're following: while `df` shows that a raw partition, namely `sda5` is mounted as the filesystem root, the other screenshot shows trying to use `lvextend` which is only required for LVM-based partitioning (your device would be sth like `/dev/mapper/my-root` instead of `/dev/sda5`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to extend the root partition using [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) on a system where LVM is not used.

Normally, extending the root partition can be pretty complicated since it's being used, but Ubuntu includes `growpart` from `cloud-guest-utils`, so you should be able to do:

```
growpart /dev/sda 5
```

This should grow the partition into all available space on the disk as indicated by `lsblk`, after which you need to run the following to also resize the filesystem:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda5
```

Obviously you should snapshot the system first before making any type of changes to disks and partitions as it may break your root partition.